# LINQ with Multiple GroupJoin

Tags: c#, linq

Imagine the following case:

Each Player (an entity) can engage in any number of Attacks (an entity). An attack may result in a Kill (an entity). Attack.Player maps to the player involved in the attack. Kill.Attack maps to the attack that resulted in the kill. Thus, Kill.Attack.Player will map a kill to a player.

I want to produce the following report:
Player A made 10 attacks resulting in 7 kills.
Player B made 8 attacks resulting in 4 kills.
Player C made 0 attacks resulting in 0 kills.

How can I do so using LINQ? I thought I'd be able to do:

```
from player in Players
join attack in Attacks on player equals attack.Player into attacksByPlayer
join kill in Kills on attack equals kill.Attack into killsByPlayer
select new { Player = player, Attacks = attacksByPlayer.Count(), Kills = killsByPlayer.Count() }
```

Clearly, this is incorrect for various reasons (and won't build).

Also, how would I create the same report, but using an inner join where Player C would not be reported because he had no attacks?

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Can you traverse from Player to Attacks and then from each Attach to kills?

Comment: Hi, Ankur. Thanks for the prompt reply. No, they're linked by foreign keys. So, you have Attack.Player and Kill.Attack, but you cannot traverse the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should do the trick. It will only display the players that made an attack and will count the attacks and kills for you.

```
using (Model m = new Model())
{
    var result = from attack in m.Attacks
                 group attack by attack.Player into attacksForPlayer
                 select new
                 {
                     PlayerName = attacksForPlayer.Key.Name,
                     NumberOfAttacks = attacksForPlayer.Count(),
                     NumberOfKills = (from k in m.Kills
                                      where attacksForPlayer.Contains(k.Attack)
                                      select k).Count()
                 };

    // The result can be read like this:
    foreach (var r in result)
    {
        // r.PlayerName, r.NumberOfAttacks, r.NumberOfKills
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Wouter. That works. There are also many possible alternatives. I was trying to find the cleanest and most concise solution, and one that allowed any number of tables to be "left joined" and their columns aggregated - without going into additional nested queries. The solution I've posted below was also a good one.

Answer (score 1):

```
from player in players
from attack in attacks.Where(attack => attack.Player == player).DefaultIfEmpty()
from kill in kills.Where(kill => kill.Attack == attack).DefaultIfEmpty()
group new { attack, kill } by player into g
select new {
    Player = player, 
    Attacks = g.Count(x => x.attack != null),
    Kills = g.Count(x => x.kill != null)
}
```